# Error in Webpack when building react in docker on TeamCity

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, teamcity, create-react-app

When I'm building React in a Docker container on TeamCity I get `TypeError: extractedChunk.getNumberOfModules is not a function`.

Our React app is set up with `create-react-app`, and built with `react-scripts`.

TeamCity is fetching the latest changes from our Git repository, building a Docker image in which it runs `npm install` and then binds the command `npm run build` to `docker run`.

This gives the following error when running:

```
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] /boost/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:249
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]             if (extractedChunk.getNumberOfModules()) {
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]                                ^
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] 
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] TypeError: extractedChunk.getNumberOfModules is not a function
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (/boost/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:249:32)
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at Compilation.<anonymous> (/boost/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:248:27)
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/boost/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at sealPart2 (/boost/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:662:9)
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at next (/boost/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at /boost/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:244:13
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at /boost/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at iteratorCallback (/boost/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1050:13)
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at /boost/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:958:16
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at /boost/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:227:15
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at /boost/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at iteratorCallback (/boost/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1050:13)
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at /boost/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:958:16
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at /boost/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:216:21
[11:12:43][Step 7/16]     at rebuilding.forEach.cb (/boost/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:530:29)
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] npm ERR! errno 1
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] npm ERR! 
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 build script.
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] 
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[11:12:43][Step 7/16] npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-16T09_12_43_555Z-debug.log
```

We've reverted our `package.json` to the last working state, and building works both locally and locally in docker image. But the error still persists on TeamCity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error originated in a mismatch of versions of packages, probably React itself. Since we created our react app with `create-react-app`, which bundles Webpack, we could not upgrade React ourselves.

Since we got it working both locally, and locally in a docker container identical to that on TeamCity we figured something was wrong on TeamCity. Cached packages perhaps?

We solved the issue by instead of doing the normal `docker run` we added `bash -c "npm run build"` to our docker run. This worked, unknown why. But as said before, this probably reset cache or something. Another option might have been to run a build with clean cache using the `delete all files in the checkout directory before the build` option.